# How to remove package names from list that showing usage stats of all installed applications?

Tags: flutter

I simply made a flutter application that shows usage statistics of all installed application e.g if we spend two hours on WhatsApp my app show it,but the **problem** is :
 It also shows package names like
system ui, builder, launcher, com.package etc.
I am using this flutter package [app_usage](https://pub.dev/packages/app_usage)
Here is main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app_usage/app_usage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<AppUsageInfo> _infos = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void getUsageStats() async {
    try {
      DateTime endDate = new DateTime.now();
      DateTime startDate = endDate.subtract(Duration(hours: 1));
      List<AppUsageInfo> infoList =
          await AppUsage.getAppUsage(startDate, endDate);
      setState(() {
        _infos = infoList;
      });

      for (var info in infoList) {
        print(info.toString());
      }
    } on AppUsageException catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('App Usage Example'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _infos.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                  title: Text(_infos[index].appName),
                  trailing: Text(_infos[index].usage.toString()));
            }),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: getUsageStats, child: Icon(Icons.file_download)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my emulator output:
[image: output]

Comment: Have you tried it in your real device?

Comment: Yes i install its apk on my android, it show different package names, i want to exclude that

Comment: You will have to identify and remove them yourself. Find all such packages and remove them. Nothing else can be done.